# Handling more than one exception

Tags: python-3.x

In my python program, I'm spawning a process using spawnve(). Now if the user enters CTRL-C during execution of this spawned program, I want to make this program stop without stopping the calling program. So I need to exceptions, one is KeyboardInterrupt and other is OSError which is required if its not able to spawn the process. How am I going to use both exceptions together in a try except block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all explained [here](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)...

```
try:
    ...
except (KeyboardInterrupt, OSError) as e:
    ...
```